# Wordpresses ACF-Repeater Template Loop Not Working

Tags: wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have used ACF-Repeater ad-on in a previous project. I activated it on a new job and making a repeater for for backend editing works fine. I can not get the loop to work on the template. 'Nothing' shows on the inside of the

`<?php if(get_field('faq')): ?>`

`<?php while(has_sub_field('faq')): ?>`

`<?php endwhile; ?>`

`<?php endif; ?>`

It is a very difficult and annoying problem because it seems like nothing is wrong. especially when I reference an old job where it worked. And support is ZERO so far. The forums are not very helpful either.

Here is my template; maybe some1 can spot the problem with that.

```
            <?php if(get_field('faq')): ?>
                <?php while(has_sub_field('faq')): ?>

                    <h5><?php the_sub_field('faq_topic_name'); ?></h5>

                           <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
                                        </span>Topic 1</a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                [contact_form]
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

also it may help to know that the backend form is stored on an "FAQ" page but there is not actually any reference to the page content `<?php the_content(); ?>` I only chose that location because it was a logical place for my client to find and edit the info. The template is called on admin page settings and all the info for the paid is organized on the template. The specific ACF template [above] is called as a `PHP require` on the main page template. hope that makes sense

Comment: Where you have `[contact_form]`, can I assume you have an actual contact form in there and are just sparing us the details? Otherwise, it looks like you're attempting to use a WordPress shortcode in which case, you would need `<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>`

Comment: That is just filler info... Not supposed to be read as a shortcode.

Comment: Which version of ACF are you using? And am I correct in assuming `faq` is your repeater field with `faq_topic_name` as a basic text field?

Comment: Also, this code works for me and produces no visible issues. Syntactically, it looks correct. Is there possibly an issue within your header or footer? Also, I tested with ACF Version 4.3.8 and Repeater Field Version 1.0.0